# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'meta.fileHashes[index]') React-Native

Tags: react-native

Hi I am trying to require an Image using React Native and running into the error:
`Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'meta.fileHashes[index]')`

Here is the code that gives me an issue:

```
<Image source={require('../assets/images/2.png')} style={{height:100,width:100}}/>
```

here is another similar use case in the sample repo that is not giving me an error:

```
 <Image source={require('../assets/images/3.png')} 
       style={styles.topadvertisement}  />
```

Both files are included in the folder assets/images:

```
<Redacted>-MacBook-Pro:<redacted> <redacted>$ ls assets/images
2.png       Signal_Logo.png loader.svg  soundoff.png    whiteheart.svg
3.png       heart.svg   logo.webp   soundon.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Find anything on this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and it's ok when I reload the simulator.
So, I think you added the image after you build the project. It will not find the image's info from the cache until you reload or rebuild.